# fopen(C:\xampp\htdocs\bluway\storage\app\public\profilePhotos\avatar.jpg): failed to open stream. No such file or directory

Tags: laravel, filesystems

I really need help please. I have been on this for over 2 hours and I keep getting the same error.

```
if(request()->hasFile(‘profile_image’)){    $fullFileName = request()->file(‘profile_image’)
->getClientOriginalName();

$path = request()->file(‘profile_image’)->storeAs(‘profilePhotos’, $fullFileName);
}

Now in the create method: 
$user = User::create([
 ‘userId’ => request(‘userId’),
  ‘email’ => request(‘email’),
  ‘name’ => request(‘name’),
 ‘password’ => Hash::make(request(‘password’)),
  ‘profile_image’ => $fullFileName,
 ]);

I keep getting the error below. Someone please help...thanks. Plus I have created Storage link multiple times and keep deleting and recreating. 
fopen(C:\xampp\htdocs\bluway\storage\app\public\profilePhotos\avatar.jpg): failed to open stream. No such file or directory
```

Comment: Post the full create method. And isn't the first `if()` function also in the create?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please take a look.

Comment: Do you see the file saved in the profilePhotos directory?

Comment: At the very first attempt, I saw the file saved in the provided directory even up to three times (three different files). But they weren’t stored in the database. So I changed the directory to another name and since then, it’s been giving this error. I deleted the store folder within my public folder and recreated another storage link. But the error persisted. Since then I have been having this error.

Comment: Try clearing the cache `php artisan config:clear.` `php artisan cache:clear`.  And does the error occur on the line that starts with `$path`? Sorry. It's just hard for me to understand this. Maybe someone'll join.

Comment: Thanks for the config and cache clearing suggestions. I did both but I still got the same error. After carefully dreading the laravel file storage docs, what I did is this ``` $path = request()->file(‘profile_image’)->store(‘public/profilePhotos’);```. Since the store method generates a unique id as the filename along with it’s MIME type. It’s now stored in the database and app storage folder. If I may ask, how can I possibly set a default image if the user doesn’t upload an image?

Comment: Glad to see it worked. For the default - add a default value in users migration file. You can point to a file location there also. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is this the correct implementation of your suggestion about the default image? ````$table->string(‘profile_image’)->default->(‘public/profilePhotos/default.jpg’);````

Comment: Yes. As long as the location doesn't change. See if you can use Storage:: in there.

Comment: I have really engaged you and I truly appreciate the time you took to explain. It’s twirling fine now. I deleted the profile image and it’s left with the default image I stored inside the storage folder. Thanks a lot.